# Checking if outside file has a certain word, and if it doesn't then add it Java

Tags: java, string, file, io, file-writing

I am writing a class where I have to add words to an outside file, only if they are not already present in the file.
Here is the code for the method what I have to write out the words in the file, but when I ran it, it went in a loop and only printed one word continuously:

```
public static void toDataFile(String word, String filename)
    {   
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);   
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file);      
    
            while (sc2.hasNextLine())          
            {
                String w = sc2.nextLine();
                
                if(!(word.equals(w)))
                {
                    FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(filename, true);
                    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(myWriter);
                
                    printWriter.println(word);
                    printWriter.close();
                }
            } 
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

here are the three data files I am using to test it

file 1:
my test file one

file 2:
my test file two

file 3:
my test file three

and this is the result from the method:
test
...

it should have:
test
file
three

edit: i switched the variables w and word, now the output is still a loop, execpt now its "test file test file ..."

Comment: Replace your `if (w != word)` with `if (!w.equals(word))`. `==` (and `!=`) compares references, not the values of `String`

Comment: it is still not working and giving me a loop of one word

Comment: Share your file with words, please

Comment: You are printing `word`, but should print  `w`. Your logic needs some adjustments too: you need to check *every* word in the file *before* you print *once*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line :

```
printWriter.println(word);
```

As you are always printing the same word. Try replacing it with your variable "w", and it should work.